# Sending apn notifications to 2 different apps from same api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios, api, apple-push-notifications

We have a rails api that we would like to use to send notifications to client and admin ios apps. Does anyone know if this is possible?  We have it setup now sending to the client app but not sure how to proceed sending to admin.  We are hosting the api on heroku now using redis and a worker dyno to send the notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

> You cannot push to 2 separate apps in 1 call to the service but you should definitely be able to make a call for each app.